# Bulk insert doesn't insert any rows from my txt file

Tags: sql-server

My Bulk Insert doesn't insert any rows from my txt file

here is the code i use for bulk

```
BULK INSERT mytablename
FROM '\\myIP\myfolder\myfile.txt' WITH (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ';'
    ,ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    )
```

I got "0 rows affected" after executing this code

My file is a txt file with 1 row for each record and each colum is separated by ' ; '
There is no header with column name inside my file.
thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

THe encoding of my file was UTF-8 BOM ! And i tried with UTF-8 and it worked !